# Solving Deconvolution using Conjugate Gradient

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, image-processing, inverse-problems

Source '''Levin, Anat, et al. "Deconvolution using natural image priors." Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Computer Science and Artificial Intelligence Laboratory 3 (2007).
APA '''

Generally 2-D convolution can be written as $$y = f \circledast x $$, where $x$ is an image and $f$ represents a kernel. Since convolution is linear operation, it can be written as $$y = C_f x $$ Using a set of priors , the equation which we have to solve is 
$$A x = b$$ where $$A = C_f^T C_f + w \sum_k C_{gk}^T C_{gk}$$ and $$b = C_f^T y$$
While solving the equation using Conjugate gradient Algorithm, we choose an intial guess for $x (= x_0)$ and 
its implementation in the MATLAB is written as ( for $Ax = C_f^T C_f x_0$)

$\textbf{Ax=conv2(conv2(x,fliplr(flipud(filt1)),'same').*mask,  filt1,'same'); }$

$\textbf{Question:}$ It is okay that $C_f x$ can be represented as 2d Convolution but how can

**$ C_f^T$ (times a vector)**

**can be represented as a 2-d convolution?** (where $C_f$ is a convolution matrix)

Comment: Why dont you try it yourself? Make a small image, vectorize it and experiment searching for matrices until you get it right. A hint could be to think about how to interpret the rows of the matrix.

Comment: I think I got an answer to a similar question - https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/transpose-of-convolution

Comment: You will need to build an intuition for this to be able to actually build stuff with it. Just relying on answers won't do you much good.

Comment: Chan, Tony F., and Chiu-Kwong Wong. "Total variation blind deconvolution." IEEE transactions on Image Processing 7.3 (1998): 370-375.

Comment: I would recommend practicing and experimenting in the softwares you use. You can read lots, but you must also build intuition for how it works to be able to use what you read.

Answer (score 2):

[Conjugate Gradient Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) is just a method to solve large scale [System of Linear Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations):

$$ A x = b $$

In most cases, for really large system, the matrix $ A $ is sparse so it can use Sparse Linear Algebra.

The nice thing is in many times the Linear Operator can be represented by a much simpler (To calculate) operation. In Signal / Image Processing it happens to be, in most cases, convolution.

The Conjugate Gradient Method requires also applying the Adjoint / Transpose of the operator. In the case of convolution it is the correlation operation.
For 1D kernels it means to apply convolution with the flipped signal (Reversed order).
For 2D kernels it means to flip them bot horizontally and vertically. This is why in the code you see both `fliplr()` and `flipud()`.
Simpler way to do it is `fliplr(flipud(mA)) = mA(end:-1:1, end:-1:1)`.

[Chapter 5 of Jon F. Claerbout - Earth Soundings Analysis: Processing versus Inversion](http://sepwww.stanford.edu/sep/prof/pvi.pdf#page=119) has a great discussion of the topic of Adjoint operators (Also known as transpose, back projection or matched filtering).

Comment: Very interesting answer.